# Create two Dataframes based on series membership in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge, t-test

I'm a beginner, I can't seem to find an exact answer to this.

I have two dataframes, the first has localized economic data (df1):

```
(index)  (index)     2000     2010  Diff   
State    Region    
NY       NYC         1000     1100   100
NY       Upstate      200      270    70
NY       Long_Island 1700     1800   100 
IL       Chicago      300      500   200
IL       South         50       35    15
IL       Suburbs      800      650  -150
```

The second has a list of state and regions, (df2):

```
index   State   Region
0        NY      NYC
1        NY      Long_Island
2        IL      Chicago
```

Ultimately what I'm trying to do is run a `t-test` on the `Diff` column between the state and regions in `df2` vs all the other ones in `df1` that are not included in `df2`.  However, I haven't managed to divide the groups yet so I can't run the test.

My latest attempt (of many) looks like this:

```
df1['Region', 'State'].isin(df2['Region', 'State'])
```

I've tried `pd.merge` too but can't seem to get it to work.  I think it's because of the multi-level indexing but I still don't know how to get the state/regions that are not in `df2`.

Comment: Can you put an example of the expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) of `MultiIndexes` and then select by `loc`:

```
print (df1.index)
MultiIndex(levels=[['IL', 'NY'], ['Chicago', 'Long_Island', 
                                  'NYC', 'South', 'Suburbs', 'Upstate']],
           labels=[[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [2, 5, 1, 0, 3, 4]],
           names=['State', 'Region'])

print (df2.index)
Int64Index([0, 1, 2], dtype='int64', name='index')

print (df1.index.names)
['State', 'Region']
```

---

```
#create index from both columns
df2 =  df2.set_index(df1.index.names)
what is same as
#df2 = df2.set_index(['State','Region'])

mux = df1.index.difference(df2.index)
print (mux)
MultiIndex(levels=[['IL', 'NY'], ['South', 'Suburbs', 'Upstate']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2]],
           names=['State', 'Region'],
           sortorder=0)

print (df1.loc[mux])
               2000  2010  Diff
State Region                   
IL    South      50    35    15
      Suburbs   800   650  -150
NY    Upstate   200   270    70
```

---

All together:

```
df2 =  df2.set_index(df1.index.names)
df = df1.loc[df1.index.difference(df2.index)]
print (df)
```

Comment: i am not sure if undestand - need compare `'State','Region'` which are set in index  with columns `'State','Region'` of another dataframe?

Comment: @jazrael, Yes, it is as you commented.  Compare 'Diff' values of two different 'State', 'Region' groups. However, all original dataframes have hundreds of rows so writing out all entries would be hard.  Instead of ['IL', 'NY'] a df1['State'] type method is desirable. Thank you

Comment: I dont understand, you dont need write `['IL', 'NY']`, see last edit what you need only.

Comment: Apologies, I misread your explanation.  Thank you for clear instruction - I do desire to learn and get better. Walking me through the steps helps the learning process greatly, probably more valuable than the question I'm answering.  Thanks much, Me